# Move one ref from child to parent using forwardRef and useImperativeHandle while have other ref used in child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like `currRef` to access  dom from `MyInput` component and `inputRef` to access  dom from `App` component. So I used `useImperativeHandle` with `forwardRef`, but I get `null` value for both `currRef` and `inputRef`. What am I doing wrong?

```
import React from "react";
import { forwardRef, useRef, useImperativeHandle  } from 'react';
import "./style.css";

export default function App() {
  const childRef = useRef(null);

  function handleClick() {
    console.log('ref ', childRef);
    childRef.current.inputRef.current.focus();
  }

  return (
    <form>
      <MyInput label="Enter your name:" ref={childRef} />
      <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
        Edit
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}

const MyInput = forwardRef(function MyInput(props, ref) {
  const { label, ...otherProps } = props;
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  const currRef = useRef(null);

  console.log('currRef ', currRef.current)

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    inputRef,
  }));
  
  return (
    <label>
      {label}
      <input {...otherProps} ref={currRef} />
    </label>
  );
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you need `inputRef` and `currRef` to be different? You want them to both access the same DOM element don't you?

Comment: `currRef.current` is only `null` because you're performing your log before the ref has been set, if something were to cause your `MyInput` to rerender you'd see that in the log it would be set to your `<input>`. `inputRef.current` remains `null` because you never assign it to a value.

Comment: `inputRef: currRef` solve the issue, but can this be done with one ref? So have `currRef` used in MyInput, but also pass `currRef` to parent without using `useImperativeHandle`?

Comment: Yes, I feel like what you're really after is to remove the `useImperativeHandle`. You can leave the `forwardRef`, and then use `ref={ref}` in your `<input />` element within your `Input` component. Then in your parent you can do `childRef.current` to access the child input, so to focus it, you would do `childRef.current.focus()`. You don't need to call `useRef()` at all then in your child `Input` component then either